How to increase the second cohomology group of the structure sheaf?
We know that $H^2(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3})=0$. I am looking for blow-ups $$\pi:X \to \mathbb{P}^3$$ such that $X$ is non-singular and $H^2(\mathcal{O}_X)>0$. Of course, if we blow-up along smooth curves or points, then $H^2(\mathcal{O}_X)=0$. I will be grateful if somebody can suggest a method or a reference.

If you are in char. 0, then  $\dim H^2(\mathcal{O})$ is a birational invariant.

@DonuArapura Thank you! Could you suggest a proof or a reference. I was thinking of using the long exam sequence with support and using the result that $H^i_E(\mathcal{O}_X)=0$ for $i \ge 2$, when $E$ is the exceptional divisor associated to $\pi$. Is this in the right direction?

Any birational map can be factorised into a sequence of blow up and blow downs in smooth centres. Thus the argument you propose handles the general case.

@DanielLoughran Thank you! I understand.

It is also true in characteristic $p > 0$, by a result of Chatzistamatiou and Rülling. But in characteristic 0, it is a direct consequence of Hodge symmetry and the birational invariance of $H^0(X,\Omega_X^2)$ for smooth projective varieties. (This last result is Hartshorne, Chapter II, Exercise 8.8.)

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn Thank you!
